# Typescript: Accessing declare module types

Tags: typescript, import, module, knex.js

For knexjs with [typescript support](https://knexjs.org/#typescript-support), I've setup the following:

```
declare module "knex/types/tables" {
    interface Tables {
        // base tables
        groups: Knex.CompositeTableType<
            // Table
            typeof GroupDB.type,
            // Insert
            typeof GroupDBInsert.type,
            // Update
            typeof GroupDBUpdate.type
        >;
    }
}
```

It works. I would like to reuse the types found in the interface.

```
import { Tables } from "knex/types/tables";

let tableName: keyof Tables = "groups"
```

but `knex/types/tables` would fail with error

```
Unable to resolve path to module 'knex/types/tables'.eslintimport/no-unresolved
```

What should I do to be able to access the declared module's types?

Comment: Have you placed the `declare module` part in a declaration (`d.ts`) file?

Comment: @sno2 No. Its in a .ts file but I'll try. It was working properly in the .ts with knexjs and showing the correct table names.

Comment: @sno2 Its still failing with the same error

Comment: Too bad, it looks like you need triple-slash references. See the docs here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules

Comment: You could also just import/export the types regularly from a file (i.e. `knex.ts`) without the `declare module` part.

Comment: @sno2 I need to declare module part but you gave me an idea to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by separating the types from the interface. Thanks @sno2!

```
export type TableTypes = {
        // base tables
        groups: Knex.CompositeTableType<
            // Table
            typeof GroupDB.type,
            // Insert
            typeof GroupDBInsert.type,
            // Update
            typeof GroupDBUpdate.type
        >;
    };

declare module "knex/types/tables" {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
    interface Tables extends TableTypes {}
}
```